# How to Create cordova hybrid Android, ios apps through terminal by using ember.js framework?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ember.js, phonegap-plugins

I am new to Ember.js web applications. Actually I want to developing mobile applications like ios, android cordova hybrid application by using ember.js framework.
How can I create ember cordova hybrid ios application through terminal and what are the following steps?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ember-cli-cordova](https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-cordova).

Their "getting started" doc has everything you need to get going: http://git.io/vIKj9

All the best!

Comment: I tried this one but not working. And let me check one more and need to check Is there any issues while installing ember-cli in my system. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

To Create Cordova plugin follow the following Step:

- Installing Plugman (npm install -g plugman)
- plugman create --name testCordovaPlugin --plugin_id cordova-plugin-testCordovaPlugin --plugin_version 0.1.0

[image]